# Does there exist any non-trivial linear relation on the components of elements of $O(2,1)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Consider as an example
$$O(2)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}\middle|\ \ \theta\in \Bbb R\right\},$$
clearly for $g\in O(2)$ one has $g_{11}-g_{22}=0=g_{12}+g_{21}$, ie we have two non-trivial linear relations on the components.

$O(2)$ is however quite the black sheep in the family $O(p,q)$. I am especially interested in $O(2,1)$, my question is:

> On $O(2,1)$ does there exist any non-trivial linear relation between components?

So far I let a software evaluate the matrix exponential of a general element of $\mathfrak{so}(2,1)$ and I get a really bad expression. It looks like as if there are no such linear relations in this case, but just because I cannot find one doesn't mean none exist.

A generalisation of this question would be whether such relations exist on $O(p,q)$ for $p+q>2$. This is also interesting, but right now I am most concerned about the special case.

Comment: Hint: Complexify and use Burnside's theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922646/on-a-theorem-of-burnside-on-endomorphisms

Comment: Thanks that gives it. The only step that remains is to see why $O(2,1)$ acts irreducibly on $\Bbb C^3$. In this case it follows since if I have an invariant $1$ dimensional subspace I must have a common (complex) eigenvector of $O(2,1)$, which doesn't happen, and if I have an invariant $2$d subspace I can take the complement wrt the defining bilinear form to get a $1$d subspace that is invariant. This argument is particular to $3$ dimensions though. Is the generalisation to higher dimensions obvious if I just think about it enough?

Comment: The proof is the same as irreducibility over the reals: Given a proper subspace $V$ find a non-null vector $u$ orthogonal to it and move a non-null vector $v\in V$ to a multiple of $u$ by an orthogonal transformation. This works as long as $V$ contains a non-null vector. I will leave you to work out exceptional cases.